# How to handle reorder point if each store has it's own reorder point for a product?

Tags: data-warehouse

In an inventory data warehouse scenario, suppose each store has a different threshold to reorder a product, where do I put reorder point? It seems to fit in the fact table for inventory transactions. I have store dimension, product dimension, date dimension and fact for inventory transactions. Is this a good idea to put it in the fact table?

Comment: Is it my question that is ambiguous or I will never have an answer?

Comment: It's been 15 minutes. Patience is a virtue.

Comment: Thanks, but 15 minutes of removing wrong spelling, I sent it yesterday. But thanks anyway.